# Practical use of OUT Interrupt endpoint in USB?

Tags: usb, cpu-architecture

Can anyone suggest a practical use of OUT Interrupt endpoint in USB 2.0?
Why does host need to interrupt the device when it is the master?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of having an OUT interrupt endpoint is that you get guaranteed bandwidth at all times no matter what else is happening on the bus.  So you could use it to transfer data that is time sensitive, such as movement commands to a motor or something like that.